# jQuery Plugin TDD Starting Point

Tags: javascript, tdd, bdd, agile, mocha.js

I have some existing Javascript code that I'm looking to port to a jQuery plugin. The code itself is nothing complex: Flickr API photo gallery with varying photo sizes, a few other things. I coded it up quickly and it's stable enough, but I want to redo it the "right way".

I set up a simple TDD environment based off Yeoman, with Grunt and Mocha, and it works well. The problem I have is that my plugin will work like most jQuery plugins, having a simple entry point:

`$( '#ele' ).myAwesomePlugin( { ... } ); // Do all the things`

and I'm scratching my head at where to start writing tests. While I already have most of the code to complete the plugin, I'm trying to go through the motions of the development being driven by the tests, and I don't know how to transition from this high-level point into the smaller portions of the code.

Some stages of the program flow would be: communicate with Flickr, gather photos (or not), divide them up into various sizes, and arrange them into a container.

The plugin itself would (ideally) only have one publicly-accessible method, but, if that's the case, how should my tests hook into my deeper logic? Should I be splitting my code up into smaller, testable chunks that aren't jQuery plugins, and then combine them? I'm curious if there's a way for tests themselves to drive that development.

Any recommendations on reading material or articles would be very helpful. I'm pretty excited finally to be doing TDD!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to test-driven-development of jquery plugins with Jasmine.

[BDD Testing of jQuery plugins using Jasmine](http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/10/11/bdd-testing-of-jquery-plugins-using-jasmine/)

Jasmine is similar to Mocha, so you could follow the tutorial with either Jasmine or Mocha.